# How to update a Flutter app from App Store?

Tags: flutter, store

I have a Flutter app on App Store. When a new release is published, users have to uninstall and install the app. It doesn't have an `update` button for users to update the app instead of having to reinstall the app.

I'm not sure if I have to setup something in either Flutter code or App Store settings.

Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Always check the pub.  This package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_update seems to be popular and respected, and there are others.

Comment: This is a package for in-app update. My question is that users don't see an update button in App Store when they are informed there is new version. All they see is open button.  I researched and found some apps have the same issue but found no solution. Maybe it is an issue with App Store.

Comment: This package is not for updating app on device but it looks like a  package to update app in store from an url.